# Morris Chart Issues

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, morris.js

I am trying to plot some data correctly using Morris Charts.

The data & chart look like this: http://cl.ly/LDZC
[image]

The data coming back seems to be correct, however it looks like the series are not mapping correctly. Not sure why there are those undefined series..

heres the Javascript

```
    var getChartData = function() {
$.get('/dashboard/chart_data', 'json')
  .done(function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data))
            Morris.Line({
              element: 'orders_chart',
              data: data,
              xkey: 'purchased_at',
              ykeys: 'price',
              labels: ['Revenue']
            });
  });
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change the line for your coding using $.parseJSON(your_json_data);

```
Morris.Line({
          element: 'orders_chart',
          data: $.parseJSON(data),
          xkey: 'purchased_at',
          ykeys: 'price',
          labels: ['Revenue']
        });
```

i have similar problem using this chart. You just need to parse the JSON object from the callback.